# Select rows with same ID/email but different value in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Select rows with same ID/email but different value in other table

I have two tables: person and email, now there are mail addresses that have the same value, and persons/ID with different values.

Can anyone tell how to write an SQL query for this? I have tried but I can't figure it out. I have found some answers but then it is always finding the match in the same table

Like this

```
Table_person.             ​​Table_email
1​​​                         email@persoon1
2​​​                         email@persoon2
3​​​                         email@persoon3
4​​​                         email@persoon1
5​​​                         email@persoon5
6​​​                         email@persoon2
```

The output should be

```
Table_person​​     Table_email
1​​​                email@persoon1
4​​​                email@persoon1
2​​​                email@persoon2
6​​​                email@persoon2
```

Comment: thanks looks much beter :-)

Comment: you must have some ID that is common in both tables, like a PersonID in the emails table maybe? How do you connect those tables?

Comment: Yes PersonID there is a person table an a email table and the common ID is person ID

Answer (score 0):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by email order by person_id)
from email e
)
select *
from cte
where exists (
  select 1
  from cte i
  where i.email = cte.email
    and rn > 1 
  )
```

or using [**`exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

```
select *
from email e
where exists (
  select 1
  from email i
  where i.email = e.email
    and i.person_id <> e.person_id
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JHFEF82373

Comment: thanks !! I tried the last one using exists. But I also have to make join somewhere, because email en person er in different tabels

Comment: How do I copy/paste a sql code here, first time on te site :-)

Answer (score 0):

---

Hope it will helps you

```
   ;with cte(Table_person,​​Table_email)
    AS
    (
    SELECT 1​​​,'email@persoon1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2​​​,'email@persoon2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3​​​,'email@persoon3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4​​​,'email@persoon1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5​​​,'email@persoon5' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6​​​,'email@persoon2'
    )
    ,Cte2 
    AS
    (
    SELECT Table_person,​​Table_email From
    (
    Select Table_person,​​Table_email,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by Table_email Order By Table_person )Seq 
    from cte
    )dt WHERE dt.Seq>1 
    )
    ,Final
    AS
    (
    SELECT Table_person,​​Table_email From
    (
    Select Table_person,​​Table_email,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by Table_email Order By Table_email )Seq2 
    from cte
    )dt
    where dt.Seq2>1
    Union ALL
    SELECT Table_person,​​Table_email From cte2 
    )
    SELECt  Table_person,​​Table_email from Final
```